# Gala high CPU usage

Tags: gala, cpu

Gala use above 50% of cpu even you don't do anything. There seems to be  no problems with xfce and openbox.

I found these with google:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289841/elementary-os-0-4-loki-x64-gala-high-cpu-usage

https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/4fb7r7/gala_high_cpu_usage/

Comment: I have the same issue. Although my GTX970 gets recognized, it is obviously not used. I tried to install the latest drivers from NVidia, but that failed with a black screen. Anything I can do to get this issue resolved? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I had the same thing happen to me, but only on a pretty messed up zesty install with added elementary-daily ppa. Going back to a clean install, gala behaves. Running this on a Zenbook ux32vd (nvidia / intel mix). *edit*
There is a similar high-CPU effect on Konsole (KDE) when running the current nvidia driver for my laptop. It doesn not happen on nouveau drivers, so maybe it could help you as well to switch to these?